Closed form for$ \int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}\ln x\ dx $
I am studying the integral below
$$I_n=
\int_0^1 
x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}\ln x\ dx
$$
With the help of WA, I am able to observe certain pattern in the results
\begin{align}
& I_0=\pi \left(- \frac18 -\frac14\ln 2\right)\\
& I_1=- \frac49+\frac13\ln 2\\
& I_2=\pi\left( \frac1{64}- \frac1{16}\ln 2\right)\\
& I_3=- \frac{31}{225}+\frac2{15}\ln 2\\
& I_4=\pi\left( \frac5{384}- \frac1{32}\ln 2\right)\\
 & I_5=\cdots
\end{align}
which indicates the following closed form for
$$I_n=c_n\left( a_n+b_n \ln2\right)
$$
where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are rational numbers while $c_n$ alternates between $1$ and $\pi$. My question is: How to derive the explicit closed form for $I_n$?
I would like to avoid integrating $\int_0^1 
x^\alpha \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx$ to some Gamma function and then differentiate with respect to $\alpha$, because it resorts to special function manipulation which is beyond my knowledge. Besides, given the elementary nature of the solution, it is unnecessary to rely on special functions.

@Semiclassical Do you have a full proof of this?

As I said, I used Mathematica; I claim no proof beyond that. The specific command is Integrate[x^n Sqrt[1 - x^2] Log[x], {x, 0, 1}], with the output being the above form (under the condition $\text{Re}(n)>-1$, which is fulfilled in the cases of interest).

Converted my first comment to part of an answer

$a_{2n} = \frac{(2n)!}{4^{n+1}(n+1)(n!)^2} \cdot (H_{2n}-H_n - \frac{1}{2n+2})$ and $b_{2n} = -\frac{(2n)!}{4^{n+1}(n+1)(n!)^2}$, so I don't think there is any nice "closed" form for $a_{2n}$, if you wish to avoid harmonic numbers.

This is too long for a comment. Gradshteyn and Rhyzik's table of integrals provides the following expansions:
$$\int_0^1 x^{2n}\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln x\,dx=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}-\frac{1}{2n+2}-\ln 2\right)$$
$$\int_0^1 x^{2n+1}\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln x\,dx=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+3)!!}\cdot\left(\ln 2-\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k-1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)$$
This is consistent with the patterns observed by the OP, including the presence/absence of an overall $\pi$ factor depending on whether the exponent is even/odd. As is standard for a table of integrals, these are provided without proof.
Mathematica's Integrate command also provides a closed form in terms of the gamma function and the harmonic numbers:
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{8}\frac{\Gamma(n/2+1/2)}{\Gamma(n/2+2)}\left[H_{(n-1)/2}-H_{n/2+1}\right]$$
It seems plausible that this can be developed to obtain the form identified by the OP. For instance, a known identity for harmonic numbers is $H_{n−1/2}=2H_{2n}−H_n−2\ln 2$; hence half-integer harmonic numbers are the cause of the $\ln 2$ term. (Dividing into even/odd cases is likely to be the necessary starting point.)

Noticing that
$$
I_n=\int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2} \ln x d x=I^{\prime}(n)
$$
where
$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 x^a \sqrt{1-x^2} d x 
$$
Via the substitution $x=\sin \theta$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^a \theta \cos ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2} B\left(\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+2\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{4 \Gamma\left(\frac{a}{2}+2\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$
By logarithmic differentiation at $a=n$, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{I^{\prime}(n)}{I(n)}&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a}{2}+2\right)\right]_{a=n} \\I^{\prime}(n)&=\frac{1}{2} I(n)\left[\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a}{2}+2\right)\right] 
\end{aligned}
$$
We can now conclude that
$$\boxed{I_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{8 \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}\left[\psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)\right]}$$
For example,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_5= & \frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(3)}{8 \Gamma\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)}\left[\psi(3)-\psi\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)\right] =-\frac{778}{11025}+\frac{8 \ln 2}{105}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
I_6=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)}{8 \Gamma(5)}\left[\psi\left(\frac{7}{2}\right)-\psi(5)\right] 
=\pi\left(\frac{59}{6144}-\frac{5 \ln 2}{216}\right)
$$
Wish this helps!

The integral $I_n= \int_0^1 x^n \sqrt{1-x^2}\ln x\ dx $ has the closed form
$$I_n=\frac{(n-1)!!}{(n+2)!!}\bigg(\ln2 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n+2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}\bigg) \bigg( \sin^2\frac{n \pi}2-\frac\pi2 \cos^2\frac{n \pi}2 \bigg) \tag1$$
derived below via an elementary procedure. Note that
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{x^n }{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx =\frac{n-1}n \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-2} }{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx +\frac1n x^{n-1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx $$
from which one can integrate $K_n= \int_0^1 \frac{x^n \ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $ by parts to establish the recursion
$$ K_n =\frac{n-1}{n} K_{n-2}+\frac1n\int_0^1 x^{n-2} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$
Then, with $\int_0^1 x^{m} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx=\frac{(m-1)!!}{(m+2)!!} \left(\sin^2\frac{m \pi}2+\frac\pi2 \cos^2\frac{m\pi}2\right) $, evaluate $K_n$ recursively
\begin{align}
K_n= &\ \frac{n-1}{n} K_{n-2}+ \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!} \bigg(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\bigg) \left(\sin^2\frac{n \pi}2+\frac\pi2 \cos^2\frac{n \pi}2\right) \\
=& \ \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{n-3}{n-2} K_{n-4}
 + \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!} \bigg(\frac1{n-3}-\frac1{n-2}+\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\bigg) \left(\sin^2\frac{n \pi}2+\frac\pi2 \cos^2\frac{n \pi}2\right) \\
=&\ \cdots\\
=&\  \frac{(n-1)!!}{n!!}\bigg( \ln2 +\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}k\bigg)\left(\sin^2\frac{n \pi}2-\frac\pi2 \cos^2\frac{n \pi}2\right) \\
\end{align}
where the starting values $K_1= \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx =\ln2 -1$ and $K_0= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx =-\frac\pi2 \ln2$ are used in the last step. Finally, calculate
$I_n = K_n- K_{n+2}\ $  to obtain the closed form (1).

Making the substitution $x=\cos\theta$ you get
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n(\theta)\sin^2\theta\ln(\cos\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Furthermore, we can substitute the Fourier series of $\ln(\cos\theta)$, valid for $0\leq \theta\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\small\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\ln(\cos\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta&=\small\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\left(-\ln(2)-\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^\ell\cos(2\ell\theta)}{\ell}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\small-\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}\,\mathrm B\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)-\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\cos(2\ell\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\small-\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}\,\mathrm B\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)-\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^n(\theta)\cos(2\ell\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta+\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n+2}(\theta)\cos(2\ell\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\\
&=\small-\dfrac{\ln 2}{2}\,\mathrm B\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)+\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}\left[\mathrm J_{n+2,\ell}-J_{n,\ell}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
where $J_{n,\ell}=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{n}(\theta)\cos(2\ell\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$.

$\mathbf{Attempt\ at\ simplifying:}$ Let's try substituting the Fourier series of $\cos^n(x)$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{n,\ell}&=\dfrac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos((n-2k)\theta)\cos(2\ell\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta\\
\end{aligned}
$$
When $n$ is even, only the $n-2k=\pm2\ell$ integrals contribute. For this same reason, only $1\leq \ell\leq \frac{n}{2}$ will contribute to the sum in $\ell$. Thus,
$$J_{n,\ell}=\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\ell+1)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\ell+1)},\enspace 1\leq \ell\leq \frac{n}{2}$$
When $n$ is odd, we get
$$\dfrac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}(-1)^{k+\ell}{n\choose k}\dfrac{1}{2k+2\ell-n},$$
which, somehow, is the same result as before ($!!!$). Note though that now there's no restriction for $\ell$...

To sum up,
$$\boxed{\int_0^1x^n\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln(x)\,\mathrm dx=a\ln 2+b\,\pi}\,,$$
where
$$a\equiv -\dfrac{1}{2}\,\mathrm B\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
and
$$b\equiv \dfrac{1}{2^{n+3}}\sum_{\ell}\dfrac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}\dfrac{4\ell^2-(n+2)}{(\frac{n}{2}-\ell+1)(\frac{n}{2}+\ell+1)}\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\ell+1)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\ell+1)}$$
From here on I doubt we can simplify further the sum in $\ell$ so I think it is a good place to stop.
